# Mongo fails to create unique _id when inserting

Tags: node.js, mongodb, duplicates

I'm building a node.js app and tries to insert several documents to a collection at once but It fails with an error

```
E11000 duplicate key error index: mydb.mycollection.$_id_  dup key: { : ObjectId('52f0ce126bee2f405a755c6b') }
```

Here is code that gives me that error

```
var my_docs = new Array;
var tmp = {'name':'','address':''};
for (var i=0; i < limit ; i++)
{
   my_docs.push(tmp);
}
db.collection('mycollection').insert(my_docs,{w:1}, function(err, result) {...
```

This is very strange. Any ideas on how to proceed to debug this?

If I do manual insert from commandline, it works and no key duplications.

Comment: Don't really know if it's related, but you're creating an array that only contains a bunch of references to the same Javascript object (`tmp`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this problem is due to the fact that your tmp var refer to the same object along your for loop, try the following:

```
var my_docs = new Array;

for (var i=0; i < limit ; i++)
{
  var tmp = new Object({'name':'','address':''});
  my_docs.push(tmp);
}
db.collection('mycollection').insert(my_docs,{w:1}, function(err, result) {...
```